# Does a final method prevent Hibernate from creating a proxy for such an entity?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate uses proxies to enable lazy loading of collections and even single-ended associations. According to Hibernate's (3.6.5) reference documentaion (*Section 21.1.3, Single-ended association proxies*), such a proxy can't be constructed by Hibernate if it contains "*any final methods*".
My question is, does this restriction apply to getters/setters of persistent fields only or really to any method in an entity class? So, does a method like this one:

```
public final String toString() {
   return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + id;
}
```

really prevent the creation of a (CGLIB or Javassist) proxy for this entity?
Does it matter if field-based or property access is used? Since CGLIB was replaced by Javassist, does this provide any more features in this direction?

I like to use inheritance in my entity hierarchy and hence the requirement to define some final methods,
for example, in the base class to prevent subclasses from overriding those methods.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the help of the Hibernate mailing list (thanks Emmanuel Bernardt!) I'm able to answer my own question, the summary is:
Final methods do not prevent Hibernate from creating a proxy in general but unless those methods don't use *any* state of the entity this is highly inadvisable.

Some background information: Hibernate doesn't use bytecode enhancement neither with cglib nor with Javassist so, in order for a proxy to initialize its target entity lazily it has to intercept any method which may use the state of that target entity.
Now it's perfectly ok to have a final method like this

```
public final doSomething(String a, Integer b ) {
  // do complicated stuff using only a and b (no instance members accessed!)
}
```

but as soon as this method uses any persistent field directly <s>or through another instance method</s> this would bypass the proxy and thus lead to unexpected behaviour.

As a sidenote this is the same reason why you should not access fields of other instances directly, for example in an entities `equals` method:

```
// XXX bad code!
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (!(o instanceof Profile)) return false;
  Profile profile = (Profile) o;
  // XXX this bypasses a possible proxy, use profile.getName() instead!
  return (name == null ? profile.name == null : name.equals(profile.name));
}
```

Comment: I think _"as soon as this method uses any persistent field either directly or through another instance method this would bypass the proxy"_ is slightly incorrect. In the final method `this` will by necessity be the proxy, so as soon as a non-final instance method is called the target will be initialized. Of course accessing any fields directly in the final method will access the never-initialized field on the proxy so this is always a problem.

Comment: To clarify what @MichałPolitowski just said: Final methods that don't access state are fine. Final methods that only access state through another method are also fine. But the final method will fail (and may SILENTLY fail) if it uses a direct instance field. There are 3 ways to solve this. First is not to declare the method final. Second is not to directly access fields from final methods. Third is to disable proxying by setting lazy="false" (not recommended for performance reasons).

Comment: If you use Intellij IDEA, please vote to create an inspection that solves this problem: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128132

Comment: This can be used as an asset. I'm using it to get the id of the entity without loading its fields.

Comment: @Robin: I have finally created myself an Intellij IDEA plugin to solve this problem. See my answer below, with the link.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: Thanks for your idea. I am now doing the same. If you can, please see the code I am using in the answer I just posted to this page. Is this also the way you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that, as the reference says, it applies to any method. Indeed, a proxy, in my understanding, is nothing more than a subclass of the entity which has no state except for the ID of the entity initially, and which delegates every method call to an actual instance of the entity class once initialized. It thus has to override all of the methods in order to

- initialize itself if necessary
- delegate the call to the actual instance method

Comment: Both cglib and javassist directly manipulate the byte code of a class so it's not a proxy in the common sense. Hence in my opinion there should be no need to really intercept _every_ method but only getters and setters of persistent fields.

Comment: Agreed, but I still see one exception: when inheritance is used and one entity has a one-to-one with a base class of two entities, the proxy is an instance of a third subclass, because Hibernat has no way of knowing which actual type to use for the proxy. Wouldn't it have to override all the methods of the base class then?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this question I have created a plugin for Intellij IDEA, that solves this problem. Here it is:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7866

The simple description is this:

> Hibernate silently fails in certain situations, leading to bugs which
>   are difficult to track down.  This plugin helps finding and fixing
>   some of these problems. Under Settings > Inspections > Hibernate
>   inspections it adds the following inspections: 
>   • Persisted class is final; 
>   • Final method of a persisted class uses direct field access.

==============================================

**A side note:**

As @BartvanHeukelom said in the comments, the fact that final methods cannot be proxied can be used as an asset: You may then
get the id of the entity from the getter, without initializing the proxy and loading its fields. This is the code I use:

```
@SuppressWarnings ("AccessingFieldFromAFinalMethodOfPersistedClass")
public final Id getId() {
    if (this instanceof HibernateProxy) return (Id)((HibernateProxy)this).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier();
    else return id;
    }
```

Please note the `@SuppressWarnings`. This is necessary only if you use IntelliJ IDEA with my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the very question: does a final method prevent Hibernate from creating a proxy - no, it **does not**. Although `The HHH000112: Getters of lazy classes cannot be final` error message is issued in Entity Tuplizer upon  building a `ProxtFactory` when a final method is discovered, Hibernate continues to execute further and does not anyhow mark this problematic method.

This happens because the proxy machinery, an implementation of `org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyFactory` interface, is open for configuration, and a developer is free to choose any implementation of it.
Default Hibernate proxy factory, Javassist-based, indeed does not intercept `final` methods, but developer can implement a custom proxy factory which not only can "override" a final method, but can do many other things using bytecode libraries like CGLib, ByteBuddy and even ASM itself.

To override the default Hibernate `ProxyFactory`, as of Hibernate 5.3.9, developer can register a custom implementation of `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` in a file in `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` classpath:

```
com.foo.FactoryIntegrator
```

and this `Itegrator` will register custom `EntityTuplizer`

```
public static class FactoryIntegrator implements Integrator {

    @Override
    public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getEntityTuplizerFactory()
            .registerDefaultTuplizerClass(EntityMode.POJO, FactoryTuplizer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    }
    
}
```

which, in turn, will register a custom proxy factory

```
public class FactoryTuplizer extends PojoEntityTuplizer {

    public FactoryTuplizer(EntityMetamodel entityMetamodel, PersistentClass mappedEntity) {
        super(entityMetamodel, mappedEntity);
    }

    @Override
    protected ProxyFactory buildProxyFactoryInternal(PersistentClass persistentClass,
            Getter idGetter, Setter idSetter) {
        return new FinalOverrdingProxyFactory();
    }
    
}

public class FinalOverrdingProxyFactory implements ProxyFactory, Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Notice that it is possible to reuse most of the complex Hibernate Proxy logic because an implementation of `ProxyFactory` might (and, possibly, should) be very simple as all the burden of implementation of `org.hibernate.proxy.LazyInitializer` can be delegated to an abstract class `BasicLazyInitializer` your `LazyInitializer` implementation might subclass from, and all you will have to implement is proxy engine-dependent logic.

All of the above applies to JPA layer if it is build atop of Hibernate.