# Where exactly do I need to avoid direct field access in the presence of Hibernate proxies?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy

I have a simple entity class as follows:

```
@Entity public class Foo {

    @NotNull @Column private String name;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Now in the face of Hibernate proxies, I know I cannot rely on `getClass()` to return `Foo.class`, and that I cannot rely on `instanceof` in the face of entity hierarchies. And I know that I should not access `other.name` directly in the `equals` method. For instance, I shouldn't do this:

```
// in class Foo:
@Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    // instanceof is fine in this case since Foo has no entity superclass
    if (!(obj instanceof Foo)) {
        return false;
    }
    Foo other = (Foo) obj;

    // hold up! if other is a proxy, then other.name will be null
    return Objects.equal(name, other.name);
}
```

My question is, where *exactly* is it not safe to access `other.name`? And is it ever unsafe to access `this.name`?

This is going in to production soon, and I don't have the luxury of a "try and see" approach here.

Comment: John, in case you use IntelliJ IDEA and you're still interested, I did a plugin to check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608222/does-a-final-method-prevent-hibernate-from-creating-a-proxy-for-such-an-entity/31835624#31835624#answer-31835624

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, I jimmied up my `Foo` class to report on field access in different contexts. Here is what I added:

```
public String callGetNamePublic() {
    System.out.print("callGetNamePublic: ");
    return getNamePublic();
}

public String getNamePublic() {
    System.out.println("getNamePublic: " + name);
    return name;
}

public String callGetNameProtected() {
    System.out.print("callGetNameProtected: ");
    return getNameProtected();
}

protected String getNameProtected() {
    System.out.println("getNameProtected: " + name);
    return name;
}

public String callGetNamePackage() {
    System.out.print("callGetNamePackage: ");
    return getNamePackage();
}

String getNamePackage() {
    System.out.println("getNamePackage: " + name);
    return name;
}

public String callGetNamePrivate() {
    System.out.print("callGetNamePrivate: ");
    return getNamePrivate();
}

private String getNamePrivate() {
    System.out.println("getNamePrivate: " + name);
    return name;
}

public static class FooSubclass extends Foo {

    public String callOtherGetNamePublic(Foo other) {
        System.out.print("callOtherGetNamePublic: ");
        return other.getNamePublic();
    }

    public String callOtherGetNameProtected(Foo other) {
        System.out.print("callOtherGetNameProtected: ");
        return other.getNameProtected();
    }

    public String callOtherGetNamePackage(Foo other) {
        System.out.print("callOtherGetNamePackage: ");
        return other.getNamePackage();
    }

    public String callOtherGetNamePrivate(Foo other) {
        System.out.print("callOtherGetNamePrivate: ");
        return other.getNamePrivate();
    }

    public String accessOtherName(Foo other) {
        System.out.print("accessOtherName: " + other.name);
        return other.name;
    }
}
```

Then I rigged up a test to pull up a `Foo` proxy object, and call these methods. Like so:

```
// I'll leave this to your imagination ;)
Foo foo1 = getFooProxy();

foo1.getName();
foo1.getNamePublic();
foo1.callGetNamePublic();
foo1.callGetNameProtected();
foo1.callGetNamePackage();
foo1.callGetNamePrivate();

FooSubclass foo2 = new Foo.FooSubclass();
foo2.callOtherGetNamePublic(foo1);
foo2.callOtherGetNameProtected(foo1);
foo2.callOtherGetNamePackage(foo1);
foo2.callOtherGetNamePrivate(foo1);
foo2.accessOtherName(foo1);
```

Here are the results:

```
getNamePublic: testName
callGetNamePublic: getNamePublic: testName
callGetNameProtected: getNameProtected: testName
callGetNamePackage: getNamePackage: testName
callGetNamePrivate: getNamePrivate: testName
callOtherGetNamePublic: getNamePublic: testName
callOtherGetNameProtected: getNameProtected: testName
callOtherGetNamePackage: getNamePackage: testName
callOtherGetNamePrivate: getNamePrivate: null
accessOtherName: null
```

I've since discovered that you need to avoid direct field access in any final methods as well. If you change any of the following methods to final, and the corresponding results will change from `testName` to `null`:

- `getNamePublic`
- `getNameProtected`
- `getNamePackage`
- `getNamePrivate`

So the answer is: The only limitations to direct field access in the face of Hibernate proxies are (1) direct field access to `other.name`, (2) inside calls to private methods on `other`, and (3) inside any final methods.